# Python, Flask - How to Use DHTML uploader to load a file

Tags: javascript, python, flask, dhtmlx

I am using dhtmlx uploader to upload files.

Here is my JS code

```
{type: "label",label: ""},
{type: "upload",name: "creatives",inputWidth: 330,
 url: "/upload_creative",
_swfLogs: "enabled",
 swfPath: "static/js/dhtmlxForm/codebase/ext/uploader.swf",
 swfUrl: "/upload_creative"
},
```

Here is my python code that will receive the files.

```
@app.route('/upload_creative', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def upload_creative():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print 'request.form', request.form
```

So...from python....how do I get the name of the file so I can save to disk?  I am expecting image files.

When I upload I see this in the logs.

```
request.form ImmutableMultiDict([])
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2012 23:59:56] "POST /upload_creative?mode=html5&1347724796791 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from flask import request
...

imgfile = request.files['file-id']
imgname = imgfile.filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `request.files` instead of `request.form`.

`request.files` is a dict-like object (`ImmutableMultiDict` to be exact, just like `request.form`) containing all the uploaded files.

Each file is contained in a [werkzeug FileStorage](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage); you can `.save()` it to a real file (it might be just in-memory until you do so).

For more information see the [flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/) and the [Flask-Uploads](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Uploads/) extension.